# Has a free neutron ever been shown to absorb/emit/interact with a photon?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

Protons only 'interact with' very high-energy photons, whether inside a nucleus or free, right?  I'm assuming the same about neutrons....

Neutrons have a small magnetic moment and a slight electric 'moment' (dipole?), correct?  They are sometimes considered to consist of a negative charge surrounding a positive charge?

I would assume that neutrons, in a nucleus or free, interact with photons even less often than protons, and that the gamma photon has to have an even higher energy than one interacting with a proton....

Lastly, I have read about 'photodisintegration', in which a nucleon is kicked out of a nucleus by a gamma ray.  It seems to happen to neutrons sometimes...

But, I am mostly curious about experimental evidence of free neutrons interacting with photons, how often it happens compared to free protons, and whether the interacting photon's energy has to be extremely high, higher even than a photon interacting with a proton...

Comment: Why do you think protons interact only with very high-energy photons?

Comment: *Low-energy* photon-neutron scattering is calculated here: http://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/nph-iarticle_query?bibcode=1993ApJ...417...12G&db_key=AST&page_ind=0&plate_select=NO&data_type=GIF&type=SCREEN_GIF&classic=YES According to eqn. (16), the cross section varies as the square of the energy.

Comment: In natural units, the cross section is a numerical factor times $\alpha^2 E^2/M^4$, where $\alpha$ is the fine-structure constant, $E$ is the photon energy in the frame of the neutron, and $M$ is the mass of the neutron.

Comment: @G. Smith. I suspect it's because that he thinks that a photon has to be short-wavelength enough to be able to "see" the inner, quark structure of the proton/neutron as that's where the charges are that permit interaction. However, a proton has a net charge and, moreover, a photon need not be able to "see" the individual non-neutral charges within a net-neutral object to scatter off it, only that such charges be present: that is, in fact, how/why we "see" all the "solid" things around us as being "solid" even though they're actually quantum-mechanically fuzzy swarms of tiny particles.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Low-energy* photons can scatter just fine off both protons and neutrons.

When a photon scatters off a proton, the low-energy cross section in natural units is a numerical factor times $\alpha^2/M^2$, where $\alpha$ is the fine-structure constant and $M$ is the proton mass.

(Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomson_scattering)

When a photon scatters off a neutron, the low-energy cross section in natural units is a numerical factor times $\alpha^2 E^2/M^4$, where $E$ is the photon energy in the frame of the neutron. (Here $M$ is now the neutron mass, but this is close to the proton mass so we don’t need to distinguish them.)

(Source: http://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/nph-iarticle_query?bibcode=1993ApJ...417...12G&db_key=AST&page_ind=0&plate_select=NO&data_type=GIF&type=SCREEN_GIF&classic=YES)

Thus low-energy photon scattering off a neutron is less likely than the scattering off a proton by a numerical factor times $E^2/M^2$.

It is less likely because photon-neutron scattering involves the magnetic dipole moment of the neutron while photon-proton scattering involves the electric monopole moment (i.e., charge) of the proton.

I will let someone else discuss the experimental evidence. I will trust QED, which we know works extremely well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer(s)!  What I had read elsewhere, in several places, said only high-energy photons could interact with protons....  None of these other answers/short articles seemed authoritative, or detailed, which is part of the reason I posted this question in the first place....

Comment: By the way, neutron do not have an electric moment. This is prevented by the symetries, and expriments about measuring it are compatible with 0.

Answer (score 0):

Observation of the radiative decay mode of the
free neutron (NATURE| Vol 444| 21/28 December 2006, p.1059)

> The theory of quantum electrodynamics (QED) predicts that beta decay
> of the neutron into a proton, electron and antineutrino should be
> accompanied by a continuous spectrum of soft photons. While this inner
> bremsstrahlung branch has been previously measured in nuclear beta and
> electron capture decay, it has never been observed in free neutron
> decay. Recently, the photon energy spectrum and branching ratio for
> neutron radiative decay have been calculated using two approaches: a
> standard QED framework$^{1–3}$ and heavy baryon chiral perturbation
> theory$^4$ (an effective theory of hadrons based on the symmetries of
> quantum chromodynamics). The QED calculation treats the nucleons as
> point-like, whereas the latter approach includes the effect of nucleon
> structure in a systematic way. Here we observe the radiative decay
> mode of free neutrons, measuring photons in coincidence with both the
> emitted electron and proton. We determined a branching ratio of
> (3.13$\pm$0.34)$\times 10^{-3}$ (68 per cent level of confidence) in
> the energy region between 15 and 340 keV, where the uncertainty is
> dominated by systematic effects. The value is consistent with the
> predictions of both theoretical approaches; the characteristic energy
> spectrum of the radiated photons, which differs from the uncorrelated
> background spectrum, is also consistent with the calculated spectrum.
> This result may provide opportunities for more detailed investigations
> of the weak interaction processes involved in neutron beta decay.